# How to host an angular on Azure linux web app

Tags: linux, angular, azure, azure-webapps

I have this Angular app that I am trying to host using Linux web app on Azure.
After deployment, I could not load the website so, after a little research, I found that I needed to add a index.js file ([Cannot GET index.html Azure Linux Web App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54236862/cannot-get-index-html-azure-linux-web-app))

That fixed the fact that I could not load my website. But it does not fix angular routing issue. If I navigate to an angular route and hit refresh, the page does not get redirected to index.html and I get a 404 response. (See http://ecominas-website-qas.azurewebsites.net)

This is my index.js

```
var express = require('express');
var server = express();
var options = {
    index: 'index.html'
};
server.use('/', express.static('/home/site/wwwroot', options));
server.listen(process.env.PORT);
```

I have also tried adding a web.config as described here [Hosting angular application in azure linux app service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56532386/hosting-angular-application-in-azure-linux-app-service), but that would not load the index.html page and the default "everything is working but no app found" page was displayed.

How can I get angular routes working?

Thanks

Comment: You can achieve it with out node server as mentioned here, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59707804/deployed-angular-app-to-azure-web-app-but-showing-the-default-azure-page (Possible duplicate)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, I have finally managed to get it working. After a few days of research and try/error, this is the index.js that worked for future reference

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');

var server = express();
var options = {
    index: 'index.html',
    redirect: true,
};
server.use(express.static('/home/site/wwwroot', options));
const allowedExt = [
    '.js',
    '.ico',
    '.css',
    '.png',
    '.jpg',
    '.woff2',
    '.woff',
    '.ttf',
    '.svg',
  ];

server.get('*', (req, res) => {
    if (allowedExt.filter(ext => req.url.indexOf(ext) > 0).length > 0) {
        res.sendFile(path.resolve(req.url));
    } else {
        res.sendFile(path.resolve('index.html'));
    }
});
server.listen(process.env.PORT);
```