# Using an Azure DevOps YAML deployment pipeline, the zip file does not unzip into the Azure App Service

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

I am building out a new yaml-based build process, provisioning via terraform, using Azure GIT repos.  The release pipeline uses a yaml file (below) and I know all of the rest of it works because the whole deployment works *except* the deploy just drops the .zip file in the site/wwwroot directory instead of unzipping it.  As far as I can tell it is all about the last two lines in the deploy section at the very bottom of the file.

Also, the package and zip themselves are fine, as I was able to manually deploy the code via Azure CLI in VS Code and it works.

**Do I need something else to get the release to unzip the zip contents into the wwwroot dir?**

```
name: Deploy $(Date:yyyyMMdd)$(Rev:.r)  # build numbering format

trigger: none

resources:
  repositories:
  - repository: templates
    type: git
    name: repo/branch
    ref: refs/heads/main
  pipelines:
  - pipeline: build
    project: ADOProject
    source: buildpipelinename
    trigger:
      branches:
      - dev

variables:
- name: tier_prefix
  value: D
- name: env_identifier
  value: dev
- name: workstream
  value: liehadmin
- name: region_prefix
  value: C
- name: rgp_identifier
  value: OURRGP
- group: terraform (non-prod)

stages:
- stage: infrastructure # our terraform methods are called from here
  condition: and(succeeded(), in(variables['Build.Reason'], 'IndividualCI', 'BatchedCI', 'Manual', 'Schedule', 'ResourceTrigger'))
  displayName: UPDATE INFRASTRUCTURE
  jobs:
  - template: 'core/terraform.yaml@templates'
    parameters: 
      tier_prefix: $(tier_prefix)
      tf_key: $(workstream)-$(env_identifier)
      module_name: 'web_1tier1region_S'
      variable_file_path: "$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/$(Build.Repository.Name)/pipelines/$(workstream)/$(workstream).$(env_identifier).tfvars.json"
- stage: deploy
  dependsOn: [infrastructure]
  displayName: DEPLOY APP
  jobs:
    # Track deployments on the environment.
  - deployment: DeployWeb
    displayName: deploy Web App
    pool:
      vmImage: 'windows-latest'
    # Creates an environment if it doesn't exist.
    environment: 'site-dev'
    strategy:
      # Default deployment strategy, more coming...
      runOnce:
        deploy:
          steps:
          - checkout: self 
          - bash: ls $BUILD_ARTIFACTSTAGINGDIRECTORY
          - bash: ls $PIPELINE_WORKSPACE
          - task: AzureRmWebAppDeployment@4
            displayName: 'deploy $(tier_prefix)-$(region_prefix)-$(workstream)-UI-01'
            inputs:
              ConnectionType: 'AzureRM'
              azureSubscription: 'subname'
              # SlotName: 'slot'
              appType: 'webApp'
              WebAppName: '$(tier_prefix)-$(region_prefix)-$(workstream)-UI-01'
              ResourceGroupName: '$(region_prefix)-Y-Z-$(rgp_identifier)-$(tier_prefix)-XXX-XX'
              # DeployToSlotOrASEFlag: true
              Package: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)/build/repo_name'
              enableCustomDeployment: true
              deploymentMethod: 'zipDeploy'
```

Answer (score 1):

I might have found the fix:

```
UseWebDeploy: true
enableCustomDeployment: true
deploymentMethod: 'runFromPackage'
```

Now, if you read [the Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/azure-rm-web-app-deployment?view=azure-devops), this is weird, since it lists `enableCustomDeployment` as an argument alias for `UseWebDeploy`, but for some reason using both worked; my code deployed to `site/wwwroot`.

Answer (score 0):

I too struggled with this and found this:

1. Go to App Service -> Configuration
2. Add a new Application Setting: `WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE = 1`
3. Go to App Service -> Console. Run the command `dir`

You should find, that the contents of your zip file is now shown, and that the site works.

You can read more here: https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE-and-WEBSITE_CONTENTAZUREFILECONNECTIONSTRING-Best-Practices

Answer (score 0):

Take note that when using `task: AzureRmWebAppDeployment@4` that `WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE = 1` will be set in configuration, but with this files will *not* be unzipped and located in wwwroot for browsing. This took me a while to find the reason as well. Per the [MSFT docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/deploy-run-package):

> In contrast, when you run directly from a package, the files in the
> package are not copied to the wwwroot directory. Instead, the ZIP
> package itself gets mounted directly as the read-only wwwroot
> directory

So it might be the case that everything is in order, and you have another issue. If you locate the .zip at `home\data\SitePackages` (use Kudu to browse) then you should be all set.

One other note, not sure of the technical stack as it wasn't tagged, but for example a Node.js site [using Angular](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61707805/410937) would require `pm2` via a startup command to actually *run* the site which is what happened to me. I was so fixated the files weren't unpacked from the .zip and in wwwroot, when the *real* problem was that I wasn't issuing a command to host the site, so the original issue was a red herring.